# General solution of $u_{tt}+2au_{tx}+a^2u_{xx}=0$

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation

I am trying to solve the following partial differential equation (PDE)
$$u_{tt}+2au_{tx}+a^2u_{xx}=0,$$

in which $a$ is a constant. By plugging this into Maple I have found the solution
$u(x,t)=g(at-x)+xf(at-x)$. I see that it is some kind of d'Alembert Ansatz, but how could I solve this PDE from scratch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solve

$$\left(\partial_t+a\partial_x\right)^2u=0$$

$$\left(\partial_t+a\partial_x\right)\left(\partial_t+a\partial_x\right)u=0$$

$$\left(\partial_t+a\partial_x\right)v=0\implies v(t,x)=f(at-x)$$

$$v=\left(\partial_t+a\partial_x\right)u=f(at-x)$$

Comment: Wow, that is a great way to solve this problem.

Comment: The wave equation is sometimes solved factorizing it $(\partial_t+c\partial_x)(\partial_t-c\partial_x)\psi=0$

Comment: That great way to solve problems is called [Operator](http://www.alternatievewiskunde.nl/jaar2015/examples.htm) [Calculus](http://myreckonings.com/wordpress/2007/12/07/heavisides-operator-calculus/) (: two references). Maybe also have a look at: [Example PDE 1](http://www.alternatievewiskunde.nl/jaar2015/dmoreno.htm) .